# intellij gradle plugin for analyse dependencies

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

In maven project I was using in Intellij Maven helper plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179-maven-helper). It is great tool, which helps to track transitive dependencies in very convenient way. Unfortunatelly now I have Gradle project and I didn't find similar solution for gradle. Do you any solution for Gradle?

Comment: There is no such solution for Gradle currently. There is a plan to add it in near future versions.